# My app keeps jumping back to an activity when there is a new node in Firebase and Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Android and just published my app, the app is called random chat and its basically a chat application. So in order to record all of the user's names I used firebase real-time database. I have stored all of the User's data in a child in firebase called Usernames, in which the child of each User is stored with the user's UID (Obtained from Firebase Auth) as the main name and it has two children: name (which stores the name of the user) and phone (which stores the phone number of the user).

The problem is that in my app, every time a new user signs up, the app automatically switched from its current activity to a profile activity. I really don't understand why its happening, I thought it might be because the event listener in the other activity is still running but i remove the event listener at the onPause and onStop of every activity and I am using singleEventListeners.

My code is :

Profile Activity

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mUser;
    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mRef;

    TextView UsernameP;

    AdView mAdView;

    private ValueEventListener eventListener;
    private ValueEventListener eventListener1;

    ArrayList<String> listOfUsernames = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> listOfGroups = new ArrayList<>();
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String usernameToBePassed;
    String useruuid;
    String randomGroupName;
    int timer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        Log.d("TDS","3");

        timer = 0;

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "my-admob-id");
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView2);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        showProgress();

        UsernameP = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.UsernameP);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mRef = mDatabase.getReference();

        checkAndSetUserNameAndGetUsernameList();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.log_out:
                logOut();
                return true;
            case R.id.help:
                startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,HelpActivity.class));
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void logOut(){
        mAuth.signOut();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (user == null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public void checkAndSetUserNameAndGetUsernameList() {

        useruuid = mUser.getUid();

        eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (timer==0) {
                    usernameToBePassed = "" + dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    UsernameP.setText(usernameToBePassed);

                    cancleProgress();
                    timer = 1;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };

        mRef.child("Usernames").child(useruuid).child("name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

        /* mRef.child("Usernames").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Dummies.clear();
                listOfUsernames.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    String username = "" + user.name;


                    makeElementsUniqueUsingSet(Dummies,listOfUsernames,username);

                    if (mUser.getPhoneNumber().equals(user.phone)){
                        UsernameP.setText(user.name);
                        usernameToBePassed = user.name;
                        useruuid = snapshot.getKey();
                    }
                }

                cancleProgress();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        }); */

    }

    public void makeElementsUniqueUsingSet(Set<String> sEntries,ArrayList<String> Entries,String entry){
        sEntries.add(entry);
        Entries.add(entry);

        if (sEntries.size() != Entries.size()){
            Entries.clear();

            List<String> checkers = new ArrayList<String>(sEntries);
            for (int i=0; i<sEntries.size();i++){
                Entries.add(checkers.get(i));
            }

            checkers.clear();

        }

        Entries.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
    }

    public void getRandomChildname(){
        showProgress();

        final Set<String> sEntries = new HashSet<>();

        eventListener1 = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String s = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    if (!snapshot.child("Users").hasChild(usernameToBePassed) && !s.equals(null)){
                        makeElementsUniqueUsingSet(sEntries,listOfGroups,s);
                    }
                }

                if (listOfGroups.size()>0) {

                    Random random = new Random();
                    int r = random.nextInt(listOfGroups.size());
                    randomGroupName = listOfGroups.get(r);

                    String randomGroupname = randomGroupName;
                    String uniqueUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

                    mRef.child("GrouplistA").child(randomGroupname).child("Users").child(usernameToBePassed).child("name").setValue(usernameToBePassed);
                    mRef.child("GrouplistA").child(randomGroupname).child("Users").child(usernameToBePassed).child("status").setValue("normal");
                    mRef.child("GrouplistA").child(randomGroupname).child("status").setValue("hold");
                    mRef.child("GrouplistA").child(randomGroupname).child("ChatBox").child("CC-Randomizer-" + uniqueUUID).child("message").setValue("How's it going, people? Randomizer here letting you know there is a new user so all your names have been switched again.So Enjoy. Mizer out!");
                    mRef.child("GrouplistA").child(randomGroupname).child("ChatBox").child("CC-Randomizer-" + uniqueUUID).child("date").setValue(getCurrentDateAndTime());

                    cancleProgress();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, ChatActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("un", usernameToBePassed);
                    intent.putExtra("gr", randomGroupname);
                    intent.putExtra("gs", "A");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry but there are no public sessions for you to barge in on",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    cancleProgress();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };

        mRef.child("GrouplistA").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener1);

    }

    public void showProgress()
    {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProfileActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    public void cancleProgress()
    {
        if(pDialog!=null)
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    public void CreateGroup(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,CreateGroupActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("un",usernameToBePassed);
        intent.putExtra("uk",useruuid);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void GroupList(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,GroupListActvity.class);
        intent.putExtra("un",usernameToBePassed);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void FriendsList(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,FriendsListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("un",usernameToBePassed);
        intent.putExtra("uk",useruuid);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void JoinGroup(View v){

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("This will take you to a random public group. You ready?");
        alert.setPositiveButton("Join", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                getRandomChildname();
            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Nevermind",null);
        alert.show();
    }

    public String getCurrentDateAndTime(){
        return DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
            mRef.removeEventListener(eventListener);

        if (eventListener1!=null) {
            mRef.removeEventListener(eventListener1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
            mRef.removeEventListener(eventListener);
        if (eventListener1!=null) {
            mRef.removeEventListener(eventListener1);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry about the bad indenting. The profile activity is the activity that the app keeps jumping back to by the way

SignUpActivity : Im using Phone Auth

EditText MobileNumber;
    CountryCodePicker ccp;

```
public ProgressDialog pDialog;

private DatabaseReference mRef;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private PhoneAuthProvider mPhoneAuth;
private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
String mVerificationId;

ValueEventListener eventListener;

private static final String TAG = "TDS";
ArrayList<String> MNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d("TDS","1");

    new SimpleEula(this).show();

    MobileNumber = (EditText)          findViewById(R.id.MobileNumber);
    ccp          = (CountryCodePicker) findViewById(R.id.ccp);

    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mPhoneAuth = PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance();
    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                MobileNumber.setError("Invalid phone number.");
            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Quota exceeded.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                               PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;
        }
    };

}

public void Submit(View v){

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(MobileNumber.getText().toString())) {
        showProgress();
        startPhoneVerification(ccp.getDefaultCountryCodeWithPlus() + MobileNumber.getText().toString());
    } else {
        MobileNumber.setError("Please enter your mobile number");
    }

}

public void startPhoneVerification(String phoneNumber) {
    mPhoneAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
}

private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        checkUserSignIn();
                        // ...
                    } else {
                        // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Verfication Code Invalid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
}

private void resendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber,
                                    PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
    mPhoneAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks,         // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            token);             // ForceResendingToken from callbacks
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    checkUserSignIn();
}

public void checkUserSignIn() {
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        showProgress();
        getandcheckAccount(currentUser);
    }
}

public void showProgress()
{
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
}

public void cancleProgress()
{
    if(pDialog!=null)
        pDialog.dismiss();
}

public void getandcheckAccount(final FirebaseUser mUser){

    eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                MNumbers.add("" + user.phone);
            }

            String UserNumber = mUser.getPhoneNumber();

            if (MNumbers.contains(UserNumber)){
                cancleProgress();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class));
            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,UsernameActivity.class));
                cancleProgress();
            }

            cancleProgress();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };

    mRef.child("Usernames").addValueEventListener(eventListener);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (eventListener!=null) {
        mRef.removeEventListener(eventListener);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (eventListener!=null) {
        mRef.removeEventListener(eventListener);
    }
}</i>
```

Im adding the username to the realtime database in a different activity

EditText Username;
    TextView TitleTextU;

```
public ProgressDialog pDialog;

private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mRef;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseUser mUser;

ValueEventListener eventListener;

ArrayList<String> Usernames = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> MNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_username);

    showProgress();

    Log.d("TDS","2");

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef = mDatabase.getReference();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    getListOfUsernames();

    Username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Username);
    TitleTextU = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TitleTextU);
    TitleTextU.setText("Enter a Username to Continue");

    Username.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
            //s is the current character in the eddittext after it is changed
            if (Usernames.contains(Username.getText().toString())){
                Username.setError("This username is taken");
            }
        }
    });

}

public void Select(View v){

    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String UID = mUser.getUid();
    String MobileNumber = mUser.getPhoneNumber();

    User user = new User(Username.getText().toString(),MobileNumber);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Username.getText().toString())){
        mRef.child("Usernames").child(UID).setValue(user);
        startActivity(new Intent(UsernameActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class));
    } else {
        Username.setError("Please enter a username");
    }
}

public void getListOfUsernames(){

    eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                Usernames.add("" + user.name);
                MNumbers.add("" + user.phone);
            }

            String UserNumber = mUser.getPhoneNumber();

            if (MNumbers.contains(UserNumber)){
                cancleProgress();
                startActivity(new Intent(UsernameActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class));
            }

            cancleProgress();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };

    mRef.child("Usernames").addValueEventListener(eventListener);

}

public void showProgress()
{
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UsernameActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
}

public void cancleProgress()
{
    if(pDialog!=null)
        pDialog.dismiss();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (eventListener!=null) {
        mRef.removeEventListener(eventListener);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (eventListener!=null) {
        mRef.removeEventListener(eventListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add signup activity code as well

Comment: Sorry for late response, @nomag, I've added it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problematic code:

```
public void getListOfUsernames(){

eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

            Usernames.add("" + user.name);
            MNumbers.add("" + user.phone);
        }

        String UserNumber = mUser.getPhoneNumber();

        if (MNumbers.contains(UserNumber)){
            cancleProgress();
            startActivity(new Intent(UsernameActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class));
        }

        cancleProgress();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
};

mRef.child("Usernames").addValueEventListener(eventListener);

}
```

Every user that signs in makes all the users go to profile screen.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the code by moving the user's ids and numbers to seperate nodes in Firebase.